# On dynamic table, change class and replace values

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering why I can't do this:

```
    var table = '<table>';
for (var i=0; i<15; i++) {
  table += '<tr>';
  table += '<td>one</td>';
  table += '<td>two</td>';
  table += '<td>three</td>';
  table += '<td>four</td>';
  table += '<td>five</td>';
  table += '<td>six</td>';
  table += '<td>seven</td>';
  table += '<td>eight</td>';
  table += '</tr>';
}
table += '</table>';

var aaa = $(table).find('tr:first td').addClass('firstrow');
var sss = aaa.replace(/one/g, 'zzz');

$('#output').html(sss);
```

I can't seem to combine the two in one line either, but I can do either the find and add class OR the replace, but not both. Help. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shindig/6nj5e9pv/45/)

Comment: You could do `var sss = table.replace(/one/g, 'zzz'); var aaa = $(sss).find...` and it would work.

Comment: Note: `aaa` is jQuery Object, you can't apply `replace` native string `function` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `aaa` is a jQuery object and does not have a `.replace()` method. As per my comment you can rearrange two of your lines as follows:

```
var table = '<table>';
for (var i=0; i<15; i++) {
  table += '<tr>';
  table += '<td>one</td>';
  table += '<td>two</td>';
  table += '<td>three</td>';
  table += '<td>four</td>';
  table += '<td>five</td>';
  table += '<td>six</td>';
  table += '<td>seven</td>';
  table += '<td>eight</td>';
  table += '</tr>';
}
table += '</table>';

var sss = table.replace(/one/g, 'zzz');

$('#output').html(sss).find('tr:first td').addClass('firstrow');
```

*Edit: changed code so that all 15 rows are appended to `#output`*

Comment: Thanks again, I was just about to ask how to keep from blowing the other rows away. :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `$(table)` returns a jQuery object containing the DOM elements, not HTML text, and this object is being put in `aaa`. `.replace()` must be applied to a string, it doesn't work on jQuery objects.

You can use the jQuery `.text()` method to replace text in elements:

```
aaa.find("td:contains(one)").text(function(i, oldtext) {
    return oldtext.replace(/one/g, 'zzz');
});

$("#output").html(aaa);
```